# how to make on load angular-xeditable edit state disabled

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, smart-table

On load xeditable edit state is enabled and it displays save and cancel button along with that.
How can I change so the state is unedit and it shows an edit button in the corresponding row, on click the field will become editable.

How to get save an cancel on when adding new row.

//html code

```
<div ng-controller="AppSettingsController as appCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="addRandomItem()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
            </i> Add new record
  </button>
  <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sortable" st-sort="parameterkey">Parameter Key</th>
        <th class="sortable" st-sort="description">Description</th>
        <th class="sortable" st-sort="value">Value</th>
        <th class="sortable" st-sort="type">Type</th>
        <th class="sortable" st-sort="active">Active</th>
        <th> Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6">
          <input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in appCtrl.users">
        <td>
         <span editable-text="row.key" e-name="name" e-form="rowform"  onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)" e-required>
          {{ row.key || 'empty' }}
        </span>
       </td>
        <td >{{row.description}}</td>
        <td >{{row.value}}</td>
        <td >{{row.type}}</td>
        <td >{{row.activeYn}}</td>
         <td >
        <!-- form -->
        <form editable-form shown="true" name="rowform" onbeforesave="appCtrl.saveParam($data, row.paramId)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == param">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
            save
          </button>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
            cancel
          </button>
        </form>
        <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
        </div>  
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;" ng-click="appCtrl.save()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

//js code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.controllers')
        .controller("AppSettingsController",  AppSettingsController);
    app.run(function(editableOptions) {
          editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
        });
     AppSettingsController.$inject = ['$scope','$http','LookupService','$filter'];
    function AppSettingsController($scope,$http,LookupService,$filter){
        var vm = this;
        vm.users=[];
        vm.param={};
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'param/getAllAppParam',
        }).then(function(resp){
            if(resp.data.result != null && resp.data.result != undefined && resp.data.code == 0 && resp.data.result!=false){
                vm.users=resp.data.result;
            }
            else{
                vm.successMsg = "";
                vm.errorMsg = "Error occured in Server..!User Could not be saved..!";
                console.log(vm.errorMsg);
                vm.saved = false;
            }
        });

            //copy the references (you could clone ie angular.copy but then have to go through a dirty checking for the matches)
           // $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);

            //add to the real data holder
            $scope.addRandomItem = function addRandomItem() {
                $scope.rowCollection.unshift({
                  /*  "paramId": "<input ng-model='row.description'/>",
                    "value": "",
                    "activeYn": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "query": "",
                    "key": ""*/
                  });
            };

            //remove to the real data holder
            $scope.removeItem = function removeItem(row) {
                var index = $scope.rowCollection.indexOf(row);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    $scope.rowCollection.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }


            vm.saveParam = function(data, paramId) {
               console.log("param Id :"+paramId);

               angular.extend(data, {paramId: paramId});
               console.log("save :"+ JSON.stringify(data));
                //return $http.post('/saveUser', data);
              };

            vm.save = function(){
                 $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'param/saveAppParam',
                        data: vm.param
                    }).then(function(resp){
                        if(resp.data.result != null && resp.data.result != undefined && resp.data.code == 0 && resp.data.result!=false){
                            vm.errorMsg ="";
                            /*vm.clear();*/
                            /*vm.successMsg=resp.data.message + " Registration Id:"+ resp.data.result.regId;*/
                            vm.saved = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            vm.successMsg = "";
                            vm.errorMsg = "Error occured in Server..!User Could not be saved..!";
                            console.log(vm.errorMsg);
                            vm.saved = false;
                        }

                    });
                };
    }

    })();
```

Comment: `shown="true"` means that the form is initially rended in the shown (editable) state

Comment: if I remove that also, it same.

Comment: and the `shown="inserted==param"`?  is that true on initial display?

Comment: it should be shown="inserted==appCtrl.param"

Comment: @Beartums How to get save and cancel on adding a new row(addRandomItem()). when new row is added. I had added this in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to put the row into an editable state on adding a new row, but I would do it with the appCtrl.users list rather than trying to mess with the x-editable rowform.

pushing a new user into the appCtrl.users array will create a new row.  You can add an attribute to the user (.isNew) which could be true when you insert the form and always set to false onafterupdate.  Then the `shown="row.isNew"` should work.

if you can't change your object model, you push the new user into an newUsers array and then use `shown="appCtrl.newUsers.indexOf(row)>-1"` should work.  in onafterupdate, you'll have to remove the user from the array.

UPDATE: as far as I can tell from the code, if you want a new row to be editable when you run the addRandomUser function, the function should look like this:

```
     $scope.addRandomItem = function addRandomItem() {
            $scope.inserted = {
                "paramId": "<input ng-model='row.description'/>",
                "value": "",
                "activeYn": "",
                "description": "",
                "type": "",
                "query": "",
                "key": ""*/
              });
            $scope.users.push($scope.inserted)
     };
```

then your html for the rowform should look like:

```
<form editable-form shown="true" name="rowform"
        onbeforesave="appCtrl.saveParam($data, row.paramId)" 
        ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" 
        shown="appCtrl.inserted == row">
    <div class="buttons" ng-show="rowform.$visible">
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" 
              class="btn btn-primary">
        save
      </button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting"  
              ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
        cancel
      </button>
    </div>  
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="!rowform.$visible"
              ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
</form>
```

That should make the row show as editable when you insert a new user.  You might need to set inserted={} in your saveUser function, and I haven't looked at your editing functionality yet.

Also, I think you'll need to create an add button to call your addRandomUser function.

Comment: @user630209, I don't believe xeditable has any way of flagging a form as 'new', so I think the answer is no.  You could use a method similar to the answer above and either push the rowform into a newObjects array or add an isNew property to the rowform, but I think I would rather do that with the actual model rather than with 3rd party directives.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/ - I had seen this fiddle which works perfectly what is required

Comment: Yes.  In essence that fiddle is doing much of what I suggested, just with a single isNew (inserted) object rather than an array -- creating new user row in the scope and setting that user to be the same as the $scope.inserted user, indicating it should be shown.  That is all happening without any reference to the rowform in the controller

Comment: since i don't understand how it works, trying to replicate the code. In my code for each new row added its an edit button instead of save button. what can be wrong here.

Comment: USERS value:{"paramId":"","key":"","description":"","value":"","type":"","activeYn":null} appSettings.js:55:1
INSERTED value :{"paramId":"","key":"","description":"","value":"","type":"","activeYn":null} eventhough these values are same save button is not shown

Comment: Can you update the code above to reflect what you are currently testing?  I don't see in the above where `inserted` or `param` are set (and I'm pretty sure they should both be properties of appCtrl)

Comment: Changes made to answer